# Create a customized list

Tags: c#, list

In my database I have information such as `WorkId`, `Name`, `StepId`. The `Name` represents the name of the steps, therefore the `WorkId` is not unique and can have multiple values for name. I am trying to build a list or an array that would have the following format: `[[workId1, [names1]], [workId2, [names2]],...]`.

I find it difficult to build it considering that the sublist is made out of a value and a list.

This is the code I use to extract the information I need in an IQueryable.

```
var distinctSteps = list
           .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.StepId))
           .Select(o => new { o.WorkId, o.StepId, o.Name })
           .Distinct();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick is to use `GroupBy` to group the original list of steps by the compound key of `(stepId, workId)` using value tuples. Then using `Select` to get the names from the group.

```
var steps = list
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s.StepId))
    .GroupBy(s => (s.StepId, s.WorkId))
    .Select(grp => new {
        StepId = grp.Key.Item1,
        WorkId = grp.Key.Item2,
        Names = grp.Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a class :

```
            List<Step> list = new List<Step>();

            var distinctSteps = list
                               .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.StepId))
                               .Distinct();
        }
    }
    public class Step
    {
        public string WorkId { get; set; }
        public string StepId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This answer and code example are incomplete and the code has invalid syntax.